# Inject jmp instruction

Tags: c++

I have created a dll that is injected inside a process now that the dll is already injected i want to edit an address so this is what i tried with no luck

```
__declspec(naked) void *shortcut(const byte* dst)
{
    __asm{
        jmp dst
    }
}

void CreatRoute(byte* src, const byte* dst)
{
    DWORD oldProtection;
    VirtualProtect(src, sizeof(src), PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE, &oldProtection);
    memcpy(shortcut(dst), src, sizeof(src));
    *(DWORD*)(src + 1) = (DWORD)(dst - src) - 5;
    VirtualProtect(src, sizeof(src), oldProtection, &oldProtection);
}
```

Comment: @HansPassant i am kinda new to the assm, and c++ so can you provide me with a code snippet to clarify that. (internet is so poor regarding this topics)

Comment: @HansPassant i am trying to adjust the source addr like this *(DWORD*)(src + 1) = (DWORD)(dst - src) - sizeof(src); but my application crashes... Also isn't the jmp statement automatically updates the EIP ?

Comment: @HansPassant, thanks for ignoring me :D

Comment: Being rude to people that try to help you typically doesn't encourage them to help you. You also don't explain WHAT goes wrong, just that "this doesn't work" - what do you expect it to do, and how is what it does different from what you expect? [I'm fairly convinced that the `jmp` instruction generated by the compiler is wrong for the way you are trying to use it, and you may even write outside the valid range, but without being at your machine debugging the problem and with only this source provided, who knows - and no, I'm not going to handhold you through the process of learning assembler]

Comment: @MatsPetersson being rude ?...

Comment: @MatsPetersson at least point me out to something i can read or do in order to achieve my goal i am not asking for you to handhold me or whatever you are sayin'

Comment: "Thanks for ignoring me" is definitely quite rude. Maybe Hans, like me, only do this in the spare time, and was comming back later".  Your first step would be to finding a x86 instruction set manual, and then taking a look at the code generated in your injection code, and see if that actually is the instruction(s) you want. If you don't know how to do that, then you will need to study x86 assembler a bit more. Unfortunately, it's about 18 years since I first started looking at x86 assembler, so I can't really say what a good resource is NOW (then it was books)

Comment: @MatsPetersson you know why i said that dude ?, because he commented and when i answered him back (in the same second) he deleted his comment and ignored me.. so i am not the one being rude here.

Comment: @MatsPetersson i know which address i want to right my codecave at, and i know i think enough about assembly instructions. But i don't know i am struggling for almost a year now without even stepping ahead that's why i am dying for help.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid beyond "debug your code, check instruction used", I can't really offer much help.